# Sum Values Based on Keys in a Separate Python List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary called `hits` below.

```
hits = {"The Weeknd": 6, "Maroon 5": 0, "Justin Bieber": 8, "Post Malone": 5}
```

I also have a separate, standalone list titled `artists`:

```
artists = ["The Weeknd", "Justin Bieber"]
```

I'd like to sum the total values in the `hits` dictionary based on the keys listed in the `artists` list (i.e., answer would be 6 + 8 = 14).

Comment: You just want something like `sum(hits[artist] for artist in artists)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
sum([v for k,v in hits.items() if k in artists ])
```

Comment: Thanks!  I see ```sum(hits[artist] for artist in artists)``` also works, which looks to be more efficient/easy on the eyes. :-)